# mysql insert escape

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I currently have this code

```
$main_cat = "Antiques-collectables";
$mcat = "0187-1443";
$sub_cat = "toys";


   mysql_query("
INSERT INTO categories
(id, main_cat, sub_cat, mcat)
VALUES
('', '$main_cat', '$sub_cat', '$mcat')
");
```

For some reasons the $mcat value is not stored properly . When I check it in the database it appears as "1" , "347"  values etc ... only 1 or 3 digits value . I think that the "-" is interpreted by the sql engine as operator . Is there any way to escape it ? I also tried

```
$mcat = str_replace("-", "\-", $mcat);
```

but still doesn't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention your data type of column in your table.
I think datatype of mcat is numeric type.

Probably by changing mcat data type to string solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you are inserting strings into the database, you need to make sure to use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on them. This prevents any unintentional problems, and also SQL injections which can really cause a lot of problems for your site.

You can, also, look at using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), which effectively eliminate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

No, '-' is not a SQL operator when within single quotes (as you have it there).

The `mcat` column probably has the wrong data type.  Is it a VARCHAR?  To store what you've got there, it should be.

Comment: or perhaps id is an auto-increment and should be omitted?

Comment: @Dan Heberden: inserting an empty value for an AUTOINCREMENT index works in MySQL.  Also, if he had that problem, his whole database would be one row (since every INSERT would overwrite the previous one, having identical keys).

Comment: Ah good point - I skimmed over the 'existing data' portion :/